# page_source do not return updated html after scrolled down the page in python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver, html-parsing

I am developing a social media web parser with selenium. I hope to get the updated html source after the Chrome driver scroll down to the end of the page.
The scrolling-down works just fine, however the page source I got is not updated. Before scrolling down, I have 15 social media posts on a page. After scrolling down, I should have more than that, however there are still 15 in the output.
Any help will be appreciated!

My code is below:

```
#set Chrome driver with login cookies
getchrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path='MYPATH/chromedriver.exe')
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
URL_by_day = "URL"
browser.get("LOGIN PAGE")
browser.delete_all_cookies()
for k, v in cookies.items():
    browser.add_cookie({'name':k,'value':v})
browser.get(URL_by_day)

#scroll down the page
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(0.3)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height    

#get page source
r = browser.page_source

browser.close()
time.sleep(2)
```